how to read the messages in a thread in a forum channel
How do I read all messages on a Discord forum thread using discord.py? I am oblivious and have been looking everywhere but couldn't find any solution. Can someone provide a detailed explanation or example code to help me out with this issue? Thank you!

Did you look at the Discord's developer portal? https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro

Yea but nothing worked, if you think there is something i should Look at tell me

The question you are asking comes under the category of "shopping question" - something that is not allowed here. You should better rephrase your question in a way that it is answerable.

my bad, will do so

Do you already know the thread ID? If yes, you can simply
messages = [message async for message in guild.get_channel(FORUM_ID).get_thread(THREAD_ID).history(limit=None)]

If you don't know the thread ID or you want to do this for all the threads
for thread in guild.get_channel(FORUM_ID).threads:
    messages = [message async for message in thread.history(limit=None)]

Keep in mind that fetching all the message in a channel/thread is a slow operation.
Take also a look at the documentation https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Thread.history
